# Display landscape and portrait pictures with same height using bootstrap grid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to create a grid of pictures using bootstrap 3 grid system. My pictures are portrait and also landscape. i want to add pictures side by side and have the same height. I have found here something like that but this deforms the landscape picture.
Here is the code that i tried:

```
 .img-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;

    }

    .img-wrapper img {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right: 0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

The problem with this as i said it deforms the landscape it makes it taller.
How can i aproach this? do i need to resize the picture?
Here is the example of how it looks know [image]

And this is what i want to achive
[image]

Here is the HTMLcode:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row equal">
    <% collections.forEach(function (collection) {
        var columnClassList;

        if(collection.coverFormat === 'portrait') {
            columnClassList = 'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-sx-12';
        } else {
            columnClassList = 'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sx-12';
        }
    %>
        <div class="<%= columnClassList %> banner">
            <a href="/collection/<%= collection._id %>">
                    <img src=" <%= collection.path + collection.displayImage %> " alt="<%=collection.displayImage %>"
                        class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
            <p class="text-center collectionName"> <%= collection.collectionName %> </p>
            <p class="text-center collectionDate"> <%= collection.date %> </p>
         </div>
    <% }); %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your html?

Comment: Best way to do it is with CSS using `background-image` and `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

Have you already heard about flexbox?

This link can help you, I hope: https://kartikprabhu.com/articles/equal-height-images-flexbox

Comment: Hy Bruno and tanks for the link, the problem is if i use the floxbox the bootstrap grid columns are not working anymore

Comment: Please include the relevant information from the link in your answer. Link-only answers are discouraged as links can become obsolete over time. Please see "Provide context for links" section in [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Even if this answer is not suitable for the OP, it may be helpful to others.